# transform Class based component to functional based component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

guys i wanna convert this code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true };
  }

  performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('result');
      }, 2000)
    );
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();
    if (data !== null) this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) return <SplashScreen />;

    const { state, navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (something)
```

i wrote this code but it doesn`t work :

```
const App = () => {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isTimerOn, setIsTimerOn] = useState(true);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
      />
    );
  }
  useEffect(async () => {
    const data = await performTimeConsumingTask();
    if (data !== null) setIsTimerOn(false);
  });
  if (isTimerOn) return <SplashScreen />;
  else {
    return (something)
```

This will show an error : 
`Invariant Violation: Rendered More Hooks than during the previous render.`

If I comment the `useEffect` hook it will run the `splashScreen`. Can any one help me in converting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `[]` as an argument if you wanted to use this hook as `componentDidMount`

```
useEffect(async () => {
const data = await performTimeConsumingTask();
if (data !== null) setIsTimerOn(false);
}, []);
```

Here is a list of hooks how you can use hooks to replace lifecycle methods

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/lifecycle-methods-substitute-with-react-hooks-b173073052a

The Reason for getting an error is your component is rendering too many times and `useEffect` is also running on each render by passing `[]` will run the `useEffect` on first render as it will behave like componentDidMount.

Also follow this to make network calls inside `useEffect`

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/handling-api-calls-using-async-await-in-useeffect-hook-990fb4ae423

Comment: There are many others errors in the code too. Not just an empty dependency. Also the error the OP mentions is not related to this

Answer (score 0):

There must be no conditional return before using all the hooks, in your case you return before using `useEffect`.

Also `useEffect` must not run on every render since it sets state in your case. Since you only want it to run on initial render pass an empty array as the second argument.

Also useEffect callback function cannot be async.

Read more about [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook in the documentation.

Check updated code below

```
const App = () => {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isTimerOn, setIsTimerOn] = useState(true);

  const performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
      return new Promise((resolve) =>
         setTimeout(() => {
           resolve('result');
        }, 2000)
   );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    async function myFunction() {
       const data = await performTimeConsumingTask();
       if (data !== null) setIsTimerOn(false);
    }
    myFunction();
  }, []); // With empty dependency it runs on initial render only like componentDidMount

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
      />
    );
  }
  if (isTimerOn) return <SplashScreen />;
  else {
    return (something)
```